# Using splat arguments to fetch from multidimensional hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I am unable to come up with a nice way to access a multidimensional Hash with supplied key names in a splat operator - any suggestions?

Example:
I am having a Hash like

```
{
  'key' => 'value',
  'some' => {
     'other' => {
         'key' => 'othervalue'
     }
  }
}
```

and a function definition `def foo(*args)`

I want to return `foo('key')` `value` and `foo('some','other','key')` `othervalue`. All I can come up with are rather long and ugly for loops with a lot of `nil?` checks, and am somehow sure I am missing a more ruby-ish way to do this nice and short. Any hints are appreciated.

## Update

Using the reply by [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192702/patrick-oscity) below, I came up with

```
def foo(hash, *args) 
  keys.reduce(hash, :fetch)
end
```

which works as I expect it to. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In some other languages this is known as `get_in`, for example in [Clojure](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/get-in) and [Elixir](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#get_in/2). Here's a functional-ish implementation in Ruby:

```
class Hash
  def get_in(*keys)
    keys.reduce(self, :fetch)
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
h = {
  'key' => 'value',
  'some' => {
    'other' => {
      'key' => 'othervalue'
    }
  }
}

h.get_in 'some'
#=> {
#     "other" => {
#       "key" => "othervalue"
#     }
#   }

h.get_in 'some', 'other'
#=> {
#     "key" => "othervalue"
#   }

h.get_in 'some', 'other', 'key'
#=> "othervalue"
```